# How to give style for iframe content?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an HTML file that is coming from the API. I want to display that HTML file inside the iframe. The iframe's height and width will be changed depending on the device. But for the mobile version, the HTML file is overflowing with content. I want to keep the content inside the iframe wrapper and inherit all the CSS from the iframe. And also I don't want to see a scrolling bar.

[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzYtG.png)

Example: The iframe should have constant width and height. For example on a mobile phone with should be 300px and even if the content is bigger than this width, content should be wrapped by an iframe. That is my question.

Comment: hi.you give width 100% and heigth 100vh to iframe

Comment: The iframe should have constant width and height. For example on a mobile phone with should be 300px and even if the content is bigger than this width, content should be wrapped by an iframe. That is my question.

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

```
<div class="iframe_container">
   <iframe class="iframe-item" src=""></iframe>
</div>
    
       
    .iframe_container {      
        position: relative;      
        display: block;      
        width: 100%;    
        padding: 0;    
        overflow: hidden;    
    }
    
    .iframe_container .iframe-item  {  
        position: absolute;  
        top: 0;  
        bottom: 0;  
        left: 0;  
        width: 100%;  
        height: 100%;  
        border: 0;  
    }
```